# Is there any Bool type function for tracked images in unity using Vuforia

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

my project is pretty simple. I want to create a 3d object and move it from a tracked Image to another Tracked Image. I managed to do it but i have a problem.

I want my timer to start when both images are tracked.I am new at coding and I couldn't understand if there is any bool type function that is true if my Image is tracked or extended tracked.

I read vuforia's script and api but i couldn't understand how it works.

I want help with this part of my code:

```
 if ( aImage.Status == DefaultObserverEventHandler.TrackingStatusFilter.Tracked_ExtendedTracked && bImage.Status ==DefaultObserverEventHandler.TrackingStatusFilter.Tracked_ExtendedTracked )
```

My code is down bellow:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Lerp : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] public GameObject cube; //My 3d object
    [SerializeField] private Transform a; // Image A position
    [SerializeField] private Transform b; //Image B position
    private float time = 0;
    [SerializeField] public GameObject aImage;
    [SerializeField] public GameObject bImage;
    


    void Start()
    {
       
        time = 0;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
       
        Vector3 startPosition = a.position;
        Vector3 targetPosition = b.position;

       
        if ( aImage.Status == DefaultObserverEventHandler.TrackingStatusFilter.Tracked_ExtendedTracked && bImage.Status ==DefaultObserverEventHandler.TrackingStatusFilter.Tracked_ExtendedTracked )
        {

            time += Time.deltaTime;
            Debug.Log("time:" + time);
            cube.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPosition, targetPosition, time / 5f);
            if (time == 5f || time > 5f)
            {
                time = 0;
            }
        }
       
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply add conditions that cover both cases with `||` ?